# Laravel - User submited a name to be displayed on the main page. Save name to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hey guys im having some issues here on what to do. Im creating a main-page.php, on that page is a input field and a submit button, when the user submits their name it has be updated, changed on the page and saved the database. This is what I have so far. I would use jQuery or Ajax to to update the name on the page correct? - Im using laravel to do this.

```
/* Main page php in views */
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="title">Hello $name</div>
<?php include ('submit.php') ?>
</div>


$name = "";
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name here">
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: You mention laravel, but have no controller code, not using blade, and don't have a coherent question. What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: User submited a name to be displayed on the main page. Save name to database - How do I go about doing this, I never used laravel and doing this for a rest run and not sure where to start, if anyone can throw me a tutorial that would be great. I know this is pretty simple stuff overall...User types the name in -> Gets changed on the page -> Name gets added to the database

Comment: Can anyone here help me out?